# no me funciona el SearchView

Tags: kotlin, searchview

Me puede decir alguien por que el searchView no me funcina?

esta es la clase ABuscarFragment

```
class ABuscarFragment : Fragment() , SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {

lateinit var viewModel: ABuscarViewModel
lateinit var buscarAdapter: ABuscarAdapter
var genero: String? = null

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater , container: ViewGroup? ,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    genero = getActivity()!!.getIntent().getStringExtra("genero");
    (activity as AppCompatActivity).supportActionBar?.title = genero
    val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_buscar , container , false)
    return view
}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View , savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

    super.onViewCreated(view , savedInstanceState)

    swipetorefresh.setColorSchemeResources(
        android.R.color.holo_red_light ,
        android.R.color.holo_blue_bright ,
        android.R.color.holo_green_light ,
        android.R.color.holo_orange_light ,
        android.R.color.holo_red_light
    )

    setHasOptionsMenu(true)
    initRecyclerView()
    loadAPIData()
}
fun initRecyclerView(){
    recyclerview.apply {
        layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(context!! , 2)
        buscarAdapter = ABuscarAdapter()
        adapter = buscarAdapter
    }
}

fun loadAPIData() {

    viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(ABuscarViewModel::class.java)
    viewModel.getPelisListObserver().observe(
        viewLifecycleOwner, Observer<List<PelisModel>> { it ->


            if (it != null) {
                swipetorefresh.setOnRefreshListener {

                    loadAPIData()
                    recyclerView.adapter = buscarAdapter
                    swipetorefresh.isRefreshing = false

                    progressBar.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                }
                progressBar.visibility = View.GONE

                buscarAdapter.pelisListData = it as ArrayList<PelisModel>
                buscarAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(context , "Error del parse o de la conexion" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show()
            }
        })
    viewModel.getPelisCall()
}

override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu, inflater: MenuInflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu)
    val searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search)
    val searchView = searchItem.actionView as SearchView
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this)
}

override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
    return when (item.itemId) {
        R.id.action_search -> {
            true
        }
        else -> super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }
}

override fun onQueryTextSubmit(query: String?): Boolean {
    return true
}

override fun onQueryTextChange(query: String?): Boolean {
    query?.let { buscarAdapter.filter.filter(it) }
    println("buscar :" + query)
    return true
}
```

}

y en el adaptador

```
class ABuscarAdapter() : RecyclerView.Adapter<ABuscarAdapter.MyViewHolder>(), Filterable {

var pelisListData = ArrayList<PelisModel>()

private var buscarList: List<PelisModel>? = null
private var buscarListFiltered: List<PelisModel>? = null

override fun getFilter(): Filter {
    return object : Filter() {
        override fun performFiltering(charSequence: CharSequence): FilterResults {
            val charString = charSequence.toString()
            if (charString.isEmpty()) {
                buscarListFiltered = buscarList
            } else {
                val filteredList = ArrayList<PelisModel>()
                for (movie in buscarList!!) {
                    if (movie.titulo.toLowerCase().contains(charString.toLowerCase())) {
                        filteredList.add(movie)
                    }
                }
                buscarListFiltered = filteredList
            }

            val filterResults = FilterResults()
            filterResults.values = buscarListFiltered
            return filterResults
        }

        override fun publishResults(charSequence: CharSequence, filterResults: FilterResults) {
            buscarListFiltered = filterResults.values as List<PelisModel>?
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Que algo ***no funciona*** no es un error muy específico como para ayudarte. Además no proporcionas un [mre] así que... cómo van a ayudarte si no saben con qué deben ayudarte??

Answer (score -1):

bien, la solución esta en el adaptador aqui dejo el fragment y el adaptador por si alguien lo necesita;

En el *onCreateOptionsMenu e metido el *onQueryTextChange y el *onQueryTextSubmit
y en el *loadAPIData he añadido *let que antes estaba en el *onQueryTextChange
Siento no saber dar una mejor explicacion, puesto que estoy un poco corto

El fragment:

```
class BuscarFragment : Fragment() {

    lateinit var viewModel: BuscarViewModel
    var genero: String? = "Buscar"

    private var buscarList: ArrayList<PelisModel>? = null
    private lateinit var buscarAdapter: BuscarAdapter
    private var queryTextListener: SearchView.OnQueryTextListener? = null
    private var searchView: SearchView? = null
    var recyclerView: RecyclerView? = null

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater , container: ViewGroup? ,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {

        (activity as AppCompatActivity).supportActionBar?.title = genero
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_buscar , container , false)
        return view
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View , savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

        super.onViewCreated(view , savedInstanceState)
   
        setHasOptionsMenu(true)
        initRecyclerView()
        loadAPIData()
    }
    fun initRecyclerView(){
        recyclerview.apply {
            layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(context!! , 2)
            buscarAdapter = BuscarAdapter()
            adapter = buscarAdapter
        }
    }

    fun loadAPIData() {

        viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(BuscarViewModel::class.java)
        viewModel.getPelisListObserver().observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer<List<PelisModel>> {  List ->

            buscarList = List as ArrayList<PelisModel>
            //Log.e("list", androidList?.size.toString())

            buscarList?.let {
                buscarAdapter.setBuscarList(context!! , it.filterNot { it.off_line == "1" })
                buscarAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
            }
            buscarAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
            swipetorefresh.setOnRefreshListener {
                loadAPIData()
                recyclerView?.adapter = buscarAdapter
                swipetorefresh.isRefreshing = false
                progressBar.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            }
            progressBar.visibility = View.GONE
            })
        viewModel.getPelisCall()
    }

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu , inflater: MenuInflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main , menu)
        val searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search)
        val searchManager = activity!!.getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE) as SearchManager
        if (searchItem != null) {
            searchView = searchItem.actionView as SearchView
        }

        if (searchView != null) {
            searchView!!.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(activity!!.componentName))
            queryTextListener = object : SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {
                override fun onQueryTextChange(newText: String): Boolean {
                    buscarAdapter.filter.filter(newText)
                    Log.i("onQueryTextChange" , newText)
                    return true
                }

                override fun onQueryTextSubmit(query: String): Boolean {
                    buscarAdapter.filter.filter(query)
                    Log.i("onQueryTextSubmit" , query)
                    return true
                }
            }
            searchView!!.setOnQueryTextListener(queryTextListener)
        }
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu , inflater)
    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        when (item.itemId) {
            R.id.action_search -> // Not implemented here
                return false
            else -> {
            }
        }
        searchView?.setOnQueryTextListener(queryTextListener)
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }
}
```

El adapter:

```
class BuscarAdapter() : RecyclerView.Adapter<BuscarAdapter.MyViewHolder>(), Filterable {

    private var buscarList: List<PelisModel>? = null
    private var buscarListFiltered: List<PelisModel>? = null
    private var context: Context? = null

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.pelis_row, parent, false)
        return MyViewHolder(view)
    }

    fun setBuscarList(context: Context, buscarList: List<PelisModel>) {
        this.context = context
        if (this.buscarList == null) {
            this.buscarList = buscarList
            this.buscarListFiltered = buscarList
            notifyItemChanged(0, buscarListFiltered!!.size)
        }
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.movieTitulo.text = buscarListFiltered!![position].titulo
        holder.movieAnyo.text = buscarListFiltered!![position].anyo
        holder.movieGenero.text = buscarListFiltered!![position].genero

        val moviePosterURL = buscarListFiltered!![position].poster_path
        Glide.with(context!!)
            .load(Constants.BASE_URL_IMAGE + moviePosterURL)
            .into(holder.movie_poster);

        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener{

            val intent = Intent(context, DetFilmActivity::class.java)
            intent.putExtra("poster_path", buscarListFiltered!![position].poster_path)
            intent.putExtra("id_themoviedb", buscarListFiltered!![position].id_themoviedb)
            intent.putExtra("url", buscarListFiltered!![position].url)
            intent.putExtra("titulo", buscarListFiltered!![position].titulo)
            intent.putExtra("genero", buscarListFiltered!![position].genero)
            //intent.putExtra("reproductor", buscarListFiltered!![position].reproductor)

            context!!.startActivity(intent)
            //Toast.makeText(context, "titulo \n" + movieListFiltered!![position].titulo, Toast.LENGTH_LONG). show()
        }

        val offLine = (buscarListFiltered!![position].off_line)

        when (offLine) {
            Constants.NO_DISP -> {holder.disponible.text = "NO DISPONIBLE"}
            Constants.PENDIENT -> {holder.disponible.text = "PARA SUBIR"}
            Constants.SAGA -> {holder.disponible.text = "SAGA"}
            Constants.NO_COMPLETA -> {holder.disponible.text = "NO COMPLETA"}
            else -> { // Note the block
                print("NO ESTA EN LA LISTA")
            }
        }
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {

        return if (buscarList != null) {
            buscarListFiltered!!.size
        } else {
            0
        }
    }

    override fun getFilter(): Filter {
        return object : Filter() {
            override fun performFiltering(charSequence: CharSequence): FilterResults {
                val charString = charSequence.toString()
                if (charString.isEmpty()) {
                    buscarListFiltered = buscarList
                } else {
                    val filteredList = ArrayList<PelisModel>()
                    for (movie in buscarList!!) {
                        if (movie.titulo.toLowerCase().contains(charString.toLowerCase())||
                            movie.genero.toLowerCase().contains(charString.toLowerCase())||
                            movie.anyo.toLowerCase().contains(charString.toLowerCase())) {
                            filteredList.add(movie)
                        }
                    }
                    buscarListFiltered = filteredList
                }

                val filterResults = FilterResults()
                filterResults.values = buscarListFiltered
                return filterResults
            }

            override fun publishResults(charSequence: CharSequence, filterResults: FilterResults) {
                buscarListFiltered = filterResults.values as List<PelisModel>?

                notifyDataSetChanged()
            }
        }
    }

    inner class MyViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {

        internal var movie_poster: ImageView
        internal var movieTitulo: TextView
        internal var disponible: TextView
        internal var movieAnyo: TextView
        internal var movieGenero: TextView

        init {
            movieTitulo = view.findViewById<View>(R.id.tv_movieTitulo) as TextView
            disponible = view.findViewById(R.id.tv_fecha) as TextView
            movieAnyo = view.findViewById<View>(R.id.tv_movieAnyo) as TextView
            movieGenero = view.findViewById<View>(R.id.tv_movieGenero) as TextView
            movie_poster = view.findViewById<View>(R.id.cv_iv_movie_poster) as ImageView
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Las respuestas de sólo código no suelen ser muy apropiadas, sobre todo entre tantas líneas. Se supone que la gente que tenga el mismo problema debe poder ***VER y ENTENDER*** la solución, te recomiendo que añadas comentarios o explicaciones de qué has hecho para que todos puedan beneficiarse de tu respuesta.